# When I put foreground image on the background, why this distortion happens?

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing

**Here is the  background image;**

[image]

**Here is the foreground image;**

[image]

**Here is the Mask image;**

[image]

**The code below;**

```
background = cv2.imread('back.jpg')
image = cv2.imread('img.jpg')
mask = cv2.imread('mask.jpg')

crop_background = cv2.resize(background, (image.shape[1], image.shape[0]), interpolation = cv2.INTER_NEAREST)

mask = np.where(mask == 0, mask, image)
crop_background1 = np.where(mask == 0, crop_background, mask)

cv2.imshow(f'{i}', crop_background1)
cv2.waitKey(0)
```

**output image After running the code;**

[image]

Comment: The two images are not the same aspect ratio, the one you're resizing will get distorted.

Comment: I have resized it, how can I solve it then? I need to keep to aspect ratio to the real image.

Comment: Then you must crop the background to match the aspect ratios.  Before you resize.

Comment: After seeing your actual output, I'd say you have a bug in your mask calculation too.

Comment: Yes, is there any way to do it?

Comment: the mask is ***compressed as JPEG***! that'll cause trouble.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Carefully look at the **data types** you are handling. All three images are `BGR`, they have **three intensity values per pixel**. In the `where` function you are only checking and setting one intensity value, so you only change the *blue* channel, instead of all three channels.

Now, you also have to be careful while composing these images. Be aware of pixel values possible “wrapping around” *(unsigned integer overflow)* and masking the correct pixels. One possible solution is to compose the image using a linear relationship between pixels values. Nothing fancy, just assigning the pixel values according to the mask matrix:

```
newPixel = (originalPixel * maskPixel + backgroundPixel * (1-maskPixel))
```

Note what happens when `maskPixel` is `0` *or* `1` (You'll need to use `float` types). You can see that the "ramp" correctly sets the `newPixel` value. The operation is also vectorizable. Let's check out the new code:

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

# Image path
path = "D://opencvImages//"

# Reading the images in default mode:
background = cv2.imread(path + "jkU1C.jpg")
image = cv2.imread(path + "QNuXL.jpg")
mask = cv2.imread(path + "6yyNG.png")

# Resize background:    
crop_background = cv2.resize(background, (image.shape[1], image.shape[0]), interpolation = cv2.INTER_NEAREST)

# BGR to Gray mask:
mask = cv2.cvtColor(mask, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

# Threshold mask:
_, mask = cv2.threshold(mask, 0, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY)

# Back to BGR:
mask = cv2.cvtColor(mask, cv2.COLOR_GRAY2BGR)

# Convert mask to float in range 0 to 1
mask = mask.astype(np.float64) / 255

# Get new pixel according to the mask matrix:
result = (image * mask + crop_background * (1 - mask))

# Clip values and convert back to uint8:
result = result.clip(0, 255).astype(np.uint8)

# Show result:    
cv2.imshow("result", result)
cv2.waitKey(0)
```

The result:

[image]

Comment: Fantastic, you fixed the masking problem!  Didn't do anything for the distortion of the background though.

Comment: @MarkRansom Thanks! I'm not sure what distortion are you referring to, do you mean the "blocky edges" around the fruits? Looks to me like interpolation artifacts. OP can change the interpolation method, maybe for this downsample case the `cv2.INTER_AREA` type works a little bit better.

Comment: did you notice, the mask image was loaded from a JPEG. that's how some of its values are NOT exactly 0...

Comment: By distortion I mean the background looks horizontally squished, because the aspect ratios of the two images were different.